# Finding aggregate by Joining Table - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, join, error-handling

Question: Find the percentage of people who died out of the cases reported for each country.

Data is in two tables- cases and death. There are country columns in both the tables. deaths is the column with no. of deaths in death table. And cases is the cases reported, which is in the cases table.

With the following query,

```
SELECT (sum(isnull(d.deaths,0))/sum(isnull(c.cases,0)))*100
FROM cases as c
JOIN death as d ON c.country=d.country
```

Im getting an answer `0.54493487236178.`

==

Aggregating separately and averaging, I'm getting the average as the following. (same in excel)

```
SELECT sum(cases) FROM cases
```

The value is 106036635

```
SELECT sum(deaths) FROM death
```

The value is 716111

`(716111/106036635)*100= 0.675343008.`

**How come both the values differ!!**

==

ALSO

```
SELECT c.country, (sum(d.deaths)/sum(c.cases))*100
FROM cases as c 
JOIN death as d ON c.country1=d.country1 AND c.cases IS NOT NULL AND d.deaths IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c.country
```

is giving me `Divide by zero error encountered.`! I understand my codes are quite ugly and long since I'm a newbie. Plz help me ..

Comment: You have a couple issues here. First is that we can't really see what is going on. But in the divisor of your first computation you have ISNULL(xx, 0). That means if the sum of cases is null you will attempt to divide by 0. The second issue is that your queries to get the values is NOT the same as the query with the calculation because your main query has joins and your sanity checking query does not.

Comment: Really thanking @SeanLange for looking into this. The probelm is that if I'm removing the "IS NULL"s, then also I'm getting the same .54493487236178! I put "IS NULL" for trying to avoid 'Divide by zero error encountered.'. Now I'm no where I feel :(

Comment: They way you put that together will not avoid the divide by zero issue here. Consider if all rows in cases are null. (Do you really have a table and column with the same name?). If they are all NULL you will have a divide by 0 error.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually all correct. Your statements are all coming out with correct information you just need to adjust your queries to see it.

We will start with the ratios you feel are incorrect. Remember on your initial query you are doing an inner join that is why your sums seem to be incorrect. If you have cases without deaths then You will actually not count those cases. your check queries should look like

```
SELECT sum(cases) FROM cases where cases.country in (Select death.country from death)
```

and

```
SELECT sum(deaths) FROM death where death.country in (Select cases.country from cases)
```

Using this query should show you the correct ratio.

For your second problem there is a chance that you have countries listed without any cases. In this case we will want to add a conditional statement to help determine when there is an issue

```
Select c.country,
   Case c.cases
       When 0 Then
           Case d.deaths
               When 0 Then 0
               Else 100
           End
       Else (sum(d.deaths)/sum(c.cases))*100
   End As Ratio
From cases c
    Inner Join death d
        On c.country = d.country
Where c.cases Is Not Null
    And d.death Is Not Null
Group By c.country
```

Or if you also want to Disclude 0 cases you can simplify the query to this

```
Select c.country,
   (sum(d.deaths)/sum(c.cases))*100 As Ratio
From cases c
    Inner Join death d
        On c.country = d.country
Where c.cases <> 0
    And c.cases Is Not Null
    And d.death Is Not Null
Group By c.country
```

Comment: I think you put a lot of effort here @KHeaney , thanks. I'm getting the percentages, but still if I'm finding the percentages of each country using excel, the values are showing difference than SQL results. Is there any way to share this data with you?

Comment: if you wanted to share the data the best way to do so would be to add it to a OneDrive excel sheet, allow people with the link to view it and edit the link into your question. Is it the excel sheet ratio that is still larger or is the SQL ratio larger now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.country, cast(sum(d.deaths)/(case when sum(c.cases) = 0 then 1 else sum(c.cases) end) as float) *100
FROM cases as c 
JOIN death as d ON c.country1=d.country1 AND c.cases IS NOT NULL AND d.deaths IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c.country
```

Comment: This will not always produce a correct result. If for some reason there are 0 cases but 2 death then you would have a result of 200% which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this @mohammed, we are almost there ( we should avoid zeros also..) Similar to KHeaney's results except '0'.

Comment: @KHeaney that for reviewing my answer.I built my answer assuming that no death without case. death table would be referenced to cases' table.